# How do I keep an audio playing after the user clicks off the pop-up in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension that involves playing multiple audio tracks in a pop-up tab. I would like to see if there is a way to keep the audio playing after the user clicks off the pop-up.

As of now, the entire implementation is not user-friendly since the pop-up gets killed as soon as the user clicks anywhere outside of it. Here is the relevant code I currently have:

**popup.js**

```
const manageAudio = (audio) => {
  const playButton = audio.nextElementSibling;
  let isPlaying = false;
  audio.onplaying = function () {
    isPlaying = true;
  };
  audio.onpause = function () {
    isPlaying = false;
  };
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
  })
  $(playButton).click(function () {
    $(playButton).toggleClass("paused");
  });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (const audio of $('audio')) {
    manageAudio(audio);
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<audio src=".../...mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div class="play"></div>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  },

  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use ManifestV2 and play the audio in the background script or use ManifestV3 and open a new tab/window that plays the audio because ManifestV3 is poorly designed and is still half-broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JQuery focusout event to catch when they click off the popup?

```
$(document).focusout(function() {
    for (const audio of $('audio')) {
    audio.pause()
    }
});
```

or this might also work...

```
$(".play").focusout(function() {
    for (const audio of $('audio')) {
        audio.pause()
    }
});
```